# How to show pop up in HTML + jQuery + CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I show a pop up? It is not displaying first when user clicks the button; I am facing few issues.

1) I want to display a pop up on the bottom (having full width having 50% height bottom of pop up touch bottom of screen).

2) Is there some css transition we can use in my pop up? We show that pop up like animation (moving upward with few seconds).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGHyb/)

```
<button  class ="btn" id="bt"> Pop up</button>

<div class ="container" >
    <h1 class="title"> Title</h1>
    <div class="left"> left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="bobyclass">body</div>
    <div class="fotter">fotter</div>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: From the fiddle I can see that inside your head things are not clear. I would suggest you do more exercises and get a better overall understanding of how the document object model works and is manipulated. That will help you resolve your issue by yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by pop up?

Comment: I container which display above screen

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery dialog features.   [$('.container').dialog();](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: @user2648752    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -100px;    this will fix the button on bottom of the page and in the middle ... it`s still hard to get what you want/need ...

Comment: @CatalinSterian why the color of body is not filled fully is space .http://jsfiddle.net/TGHyb/1/

Comment: Not left part and right part (color should filed its space in body , left and right)

Comment: body{
    background-color: lightblue;
    
}

Comment: You can use [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) Example is http://jsfiddle.net/TGHyb/2/

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mJyuP/1/) example

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Every day we learn something :) As you suggest I have updated my answer.